# How can I set RatingBar in list view by server response

Tags: android, ratingbar

I'm Playing around in android and right now i added rating bars to a list view, the bars actual rating comes by from a server resposnse which is then stored into a arraylist which is then should be sent to the list view with dataadapter. problem is I don't know how to inflate the rating bar on run time by the response given, ideas?
heres my code:

```
/**
 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
 * **/

protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog after getting all score
    pDialog.dismiss();
    // updating UI from Background Thread
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {

          /**
          * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
          * */

          ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( 
               BusinessActivity.this, businessArrayList,
               R.layout.business_list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_SCORE },
               new int[] { R.id.player_name, R.id.player_email, R.id.player_rating });

               // updating listview
               setListAdapter(adapter);
               }
          });

      }     
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RatingBar value can be easily set by passing the value to the method setRating()

```
RatingBar rb=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
/*
*After you get response from server, assuming String serverResponse contains the value.
*/
rb.setRating(Float.parseFloat(serverResponse));
```

Comment: setrating has no effect in my case